# XMLStreamWriter missing exceptions?

Tags: java, xml, stax, xmlstreamwriter

I'm currently looking into writing a loose port of XMLStreamWriter to another environment, and trying to get a handle on its namespace logic. [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) for this class seems to specify that with namespace repairing disabled, attempting to write an element/attribute using a namespace URI already bound to some prefix, using a *different* prefix, should cause an XMLStreamException. But I don't see this behaviour. With the following code:

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    String BOB = "http://www.bob.com/"
    XMLOutputFactory fac = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    fac.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces", false); // default
    XMLStreamWriter writer = fac.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("tst.xml"));

    writer.writeStartElement("bob", "root", BOB);
    writer.setPrefix("bob", BOB);
    writer.writeNamespace("bob", BOB);
    writer.writeAttribute("notbob", BOB, "attr", "value"); // Should fail?
    writer.writeStartElement("notbob", "firstinner", BOB); // Should fail?
    writer.writeEndElement();
    writer.writeEndElement();
    writer.writeEndDocument();

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

I would expect both lines using the `"notbob"` prefix for the same namespace URI already bound to `"bob"` to throw exceptions. Instead, the code completes normally, and `tst.xml` contains

```
<bob:root xmlns:bob="http://www.bob.com" notbob:attr="value">
    <notbob:firstinner></notbob:firstinner>
</bob:root>
```

Am I misunderstanding, or is this behaviour incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> attempting to write an element/attribute using a namespace URI already bound to some prefix, using a different prefix, should cause an XMLStreamException.

XML allows binding multiple different prefixes to the same namespace URI. Therefore throwing an `XMLStreamException` in that situation would violate the XML specification.

Comment: That makes sense - so can we therefore consider Oracle's documentation (I've fixed the link above) to be incorrect?

Comment: I would say that the documentation is incorrect. That doesn't surprise me because the StAX specification is known to be of very poor quality.